# Python - Dictionary with Grade Range

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary with Grade Ranges as shown below:

```
grade_boundaries = {
    'A': [70, 100],
    'B': [60, 69],
    'C': [50, 59],
    'D': [40, 49],
    'E': [30, 39],
    'F': [0, 29],
}
```

I am fairly new to Python and was wondering, how I can read this dictionary such that I can extract the lower boundary as well as the upper boundary for each grade while comparing an input number. I am able to handle dictionary when there is a single value for the key, but in this scenario, I am not sure how to write the code.

Comment: Hi, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should include some code/attempt made at solving the issue.

Comment: `grade_boundaries["A"]` returns `[70,100]`, which is a list, so you already get both bounds. If you want to use a specific one, you can use `grade_boundaries["A"][0]`, which returns `70`.

Comment: Do you want a function that takes in a number and outputs the grade?

Comment: *while comparing an input number.* - write this logic. At least, write logic where you're getting input number

Comment: Thank you @Zinki, I got the solution from your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if value >= grade_boundaries['A'][0] and value <= grade_boundaries['A'][1]:
    print("value is in grade A")
```

If you wish, you may extract both boundaries at the same time too:

```
(lower_bound, upper_bound) = grade_boundaries['A']
```

If you want to compare all at once:

```
for grade in grade_boundaries:
    if value >= grade_boundaries[grade][0] and value <= grade_boundaries[grade][1]:
        print("value is in grade " + grade)
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something like this. My only issue was I wasn't sure on how to isolate the two bounds.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bisect()` method from `bisect` module:

```
from bisect import bisect

grades='FEDCBA' #or you can use 'ABCDEF'[::-1]
score = 62

grades[bisect([30, 40, 50, 60, 70], score)]
#B
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get a letter grade from a number grade? If so, this should do the trick:

```
GRADE_BOUNDARIES = {
    'A': [70, 100],
    'B': [60, 69],
    'C': [50, 59],
    'D': [40, 49],
    'E': [30, 39],
    'F': [0, 29],
}

def get_grade(number_grade):
    for letter, bounds in GRADE_BOUNDARIES.items():
        if number_grade >= bounds[0] and number_grade <= bounds[1]:
            return letter
    raise ValueError('Invalid number grade')
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a similar solution.